# Gsap scrolltrigger confusion

Tags: html, jquery, css, gsap

I have a div and some scss like so:

```
<div class="box"> 
   <h1 id="#h1-1">Title</h1>
    <img id="arrowimg"src="img/arrowdown.png"/>
    <div class="innerbox">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#A">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#B">B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#C">C</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <p> A paragraph within the div</p>
   
      <p>Another paragraph within the div</p>
   
      <p>Yet another paragraph within the div</p>

      <div id="B">

        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      </div>

      <div id="C">

        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.box {
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color: rgb(146, 134, 219);
  overflow:hidden;
}


img {
  position:absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 760px;
  left: 500px;
}

.active {
  position:absolute;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.innerbox {
  display:none;
}
```

I have some Gsap code here that controls the expanding and contracting box div:

```
 gsap.plugin(ScrollTrigger);

var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var tl = gsap
  .timeline({ reversed: true }),
  .fromTo(
    ".box",
    { top: 700, left: 400, height: 50, width: 200 },
    {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: "#arrowimg",
        start: "top bottom",
        markers: true},
      ease: "power3.in",
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      duration: 0.45
    }
  );
```

I am very new to Gsap, obviously.

Before I had it where if you click on the div it would expand and contract. But it registers every click as a box click -- even in the navbar so I then decided I should use a scroll. If I can't get the scroll to work, maybe a button would be better than having the box clicked on?

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/Hamlington/pen/yLVvoQX

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Hamlington. Please make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It might be easiest to use something like CodePen to do so. We have [a starter template](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/aYYOdN) to help get you started.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, about that. I made a little pen but it's still messy...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few JS syntax errors with your CodePen. You can view them by opening up your developer tools (F12) and fixing them one by one. How to fix them:

- It's `gsap.registerPlugin()`, not `.plugin()`.
- You have an extra `,` between your timeline and your tween. Remove that.
- `gsap` is not defined. Make sure to load it (on CodePen you can do so by clicking the cog icon next to GSAP and then entering "GSAP" into the search field).
- `ScrollTrigger` is not defined. Make sure to load that also (same thing but search for "ScrollTrigger").

Once you've fixed the syntax errors, it renders but doesn't do what you want. Some other things to improve:

- You're making one of [the most common ScrollTrigger mistakes](https://greensock.com/st-mistakes/) — including a ScrollTrigger in a tween that's within a timeline. Doing so doesn't make much sense as both the ScrollTrigger and timeline will try to control the animation. Place the ScrollTrigger on the timeline instead.
- I'm not sure why you have `reversed: true` on your timeline.
- You should avoid animating non-performant properties like the width, height, top, right, etc. whenever possible. Try to stick to animating performant properties like transforms instead whenever you can.
- It's slightly better to stick to relative tweens like `.to()` and `.from()` instead of using `.fromTo()`. It also helps you animate [more efficiently](https://css-tricks.com/tips-for-writing-animation-code-efficiently/).

After making all of those changes, you should get [this demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/oNYEGMX?editors=0110). Now whether or not that's the effect that you're going for, I can't say.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry about all that, I should've checked it more properly. I made this new codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/Hamlington/pen/yLVvoQX) if you would like to see what I am trying to do. However I think maybe scrolltrigger isn't the right library? It immediately gets triggered...

Comment: @Hamlington It's user error, not an issue with ScrollTrigger. 1) Your start position is before negative so it *should* start immediately or else it'd never start. And 2) Your document doesn't have any scrolling so if it were positive it wouldn't ever be reached.I highly suggest that you watch the video in [the ScrollTrigger documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/) and look at some of [the ScrollTrigger demos](https://greensock.com/st-demos/) to better understand how it works.

Comment: Heck. Okay. I was hoping I could have it at that position. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What do you mean "have it at that position"? Do you mean that part of the viewport? If so, that's perfectly valid. But you need to change the ScrollTrigger's start and end values to something else if you don't want it to start immediately...